# Minimizing a variable by maximizing two functions

Tags: optimization

I have below objective function: 
$$ \min_{x\geq 0} (\max \{ x, 1/x \} )$$

where, $x \geq 0$.

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed for this? 
Matlab says minimum value for $x$ is $0.1$, since I set boundary to .1, but thats not intuitive.

Comment: minimum value for x? I'm pretty sure you want minimum value for your function, which would be 1. X is free.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit? I tried by plotting the two functions but I failed to understand the question basically.

Answer (score 2):

You have two functions, *x* and *1/x*. If you plot them, you'll see that until *x=1* the second function dominates (its plot is higher than the plot of the first function), and after that point, the first dominates.

> [image]

So, *max* just chooses the dominating function.

The *min* here is where those functions meet - since *1/x* decreases until x=1 and *x* increases after x=1.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is 1/x from 0 to 1 and x from 1 to infinity.

Since 1/x monotonically decreases, consider if the minimum was at x<1. Then there would be a number a little bit less than it at an x a little bit greater than it.

Vice versa for x>1.

Now consider boundary conditions (namely x=0 and x=1).

Comment: Thank u. I kind of trying to convince myself. The answer seems to be x =1.